# Input to Graylog

Tags: logging, logstash, graylog2

I am working on a tool to help me in troubleshooting network issues, I need to input Log messages in .txt or.log format into any Log analyzing tool.
These log (.txt or .log) files are essentially all the logs from a networking device. I am looking at using Graylog. I have tried to push individual log messages(a single row in the log file) using netcat, but the message is not getting parsed. I need to understand if i have to convert the text file into any specific format(GELF?)? If so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a `Raw/Plaintext input TCP'` or `UDP` to receive the plain text message from `nc`.

Or,
using the `graylog-collector-sidecar` together with `nxlog` to collect the file content easily.